# Segmentation fault due to unused int

Tags: c

I don't understand why my declaration of int y is preventing my program from suffering a segmentation fault. The program does as intended with the declaration there, but gives me a segmentation fault if I comment it out or delete it:

```
uint8_t chunk[CHUNKS];
int x = 0; int y;
char filename[6];
FILE *card = fopen(argv[1], "r");
FILE *img = fopen(filename, "w");

//reads 512 byte chunks
while (fread(chunk, sizeof(uint8_t), CHUNKS, card) >= CHUNKS)
{
    //checks first 4 bytes for jpeg signature
    if (chunk[0] == 0xff && chunk[1] == 0xd8 && chunk[2] == 0xff && (chunk[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    {
        //if second or more jpeg, close old file first
        if (x > 0)
        {
            fclose(img);
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", x);
            x++;
            img = fopen(filename, "w");
            //WCHUNKS += 512;
            fwrite(chunk, sizeof(uint8_t)*CHUNKS, 1, img);
        }
        
        
        //if first jpeg
        else
        {
            x++;
            fclose(img);
            //printf("I found %i Jpegs\n", x);
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", 0);
            img = fopen(filename, "w");
            fwrite (chunk, sizeof(uint8_t)*CHUNKS, 1, img);
            //WCHUNKS += 512;
        }
    }
    
    //if not a new jpeg, continue writing to current file
    else
    {
        //WCHUNKS += 512;
        fwrite (chunk, sizeof(uint8_t)*CHUNKS, 1, img);
        
    }
}

fclose(img);
fclose(card);
}
```

Comment: The array filename is not initialized char filename[6];
FILE *card = fopen(argv[1], "r");
FILE *img = fopen(filename, "w");

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, the line:

```
sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", x);
```

Writes 8 bytes in to an array of 6 chars, thus writing past the end of the array.

But why would declaring an extra variable help?

Well technically, writing past the end of an array in C is undefined behavior, but in practice, there is always something in that extra memory, and local variables are usually arranged continuously on the stack.

By declaring an extra unused `int` just before your `filename` array, the way your compiler arranges those variables, you actually add 4 (maybe 8) more bytes to your array.

Without them, you would clobber `x` causing it to have a huge number which would force the `sprintf` write even more bytes past the end of the array, which would now clobber some memory that is not allocated for variables, and that is how you get your segmentation fault.

You can usually look at the assembly, or use a debugger to find out how your variables are arranged in memory and thus get some idea what will happen when you write past one of them.

Comment: Thank you. It definitely has something to do with that array. So I understand the logic of it being 7  + 1 characters with /0. I change the array to char filename[7], still gives a seg fault. Funnily enough, when I change it to char filename[10], the fault goes away, but nothing under. I'm not sure whats going on with that. I will try my best to wrap my head around the debugging tool in my compiler. Thanks again!

Comment: A `char` array "string" always needs to be the length (in characters) of the string, plus 1 to account for the null terminating character.

Comment: @ChrisDutton I understand. So for 000.jpg, I have to declare char filename[7] right? So that 000.jpg\0 fits in indexes 0 through 7. But I tried declaring filename[7], even [8], [9]. Those all caused segmentation faults. only at [10] did the fault go away. I guess I'm wondering how exactly the fault is occurring.

Comment: `000.jpg` is actually 7 characters, so add the `'\0'` and it's 8. I'm not getting a segmentation fault when I declare `str` as `char str[8];` and populate it with `sprintf(str, "%03i.jpg", 0);`. It will segfault if I go with `char str[7];`.

Comment: @ChrisDutton so wouldn't it map out like this if we had an array of size [7]?

filename[0] : '0'
filename[1] : '0'
filename[2] : '0'
filename[3] : '.'
filename[4] : 'j'
filename[5] : 'p'
filename[6] : 'g'
filename[7] : '/0'

i tried [8] and am still getting a seg fault. I guess somewhere else in my code might be causing it...

Comment: That's exactly how it would map out to use the 8 characters.

Comment: I figured out with someone helping me that the problem was opening filename before initializing it before entering the while loop: "That was creating the weird extra file when you are processing the blocks before the first jpg header is found.  If you properly create "filename" before that, then everything is fine. As for why it worked with a 10 byte "filename" and not with 8 bytes, that's probably luck that when it was 10 bytes, there was enough garbage data there that resembled a name that can be used as a file name and not raise an exception."